# Water condensation around my finger when i touch something cold

Tags: condensation

Normally condensation happens when hot air meets a cold object such as our breath and our car window in a cold day.

But when i touch something cold such as a cold water bottle or metal of my trimming machine, i see water condensate around my finger/hand. How is this possible? I am warming the surface of the bottle/metal with my body. Why is water suddenly condensating on warming object?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hand is introducing additional moisture; either some is already on your skin and/or it is warming some of the moisture already on the device.

This warm vapor then encounters the warming-but-still-cold device nearby and condenses.

Comment: I tried it again with my hand and metal as dry as possible first. And then i tried it after wetting my hand and metal. The effect is much much more visible when my hand and metal is wet. Your explanation seems to be true. Thanks for answering my question from other side of the world :D